# Tell me how to do the semi liquid layout without javascript, i feel I'm missing something simple

Tags: css, liquid-layout

Okay, first off I'm supporting back to IE7, so box-sizing is out.

I've got a fixed size header and footer (say 80px each) positioned to the top and bottom of the window, respectively.

I want a div to take up all he space between, regardless of window size. Easy breezy with JavaScript, but is there a way to do it with just CSS?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLrPF/ based on my James Dean sticky footer http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer can do that. IE7 would need a little extra love, which can be done.

**Edit:**

This is the IE7+ solution that will work as requested.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#header-wrapper, #content-wrapper, #footer-wrapper {
    display: table-row;
}
#header, #content, #footer {
    display: table-cell;
}
#header, #footer {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: orange;
}
#content {
    background-color: green;
}

<body>
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <div id="header">header</div>
    </div>

    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="content">content</div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer-wrapper">
        <div id="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks and you're welcome :), but I think I forgot that the requirement was that the content part fills the remainder of the page even if it's not high enough to fill the window - my example doesn't do that by itself, although it fills and correctly pushes the content once the window height is reached. This is in fact quite a deep problem and I'll try to come up with something to fix that and will update this post. Using min-height on the body can pretty much make it work, but I'm curious how this would be done without and fully flexible. Can already see display: table-row being used..

Comment: Updated with a IE7+ solution which exploits the table behavior on regular elements and is as flexible as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a sticky footer. Example : http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/